# Loading ModelCheckpoint in tensorflow 2

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, keras, tensorflow2.0, tf.keras

In keras using tensorflow 1 I could `ModelCheckpoint(filepath)` and the saved file was a called `filepath` and then I could call `model = load_model(filepath)` to load the saved model.

Now the equivalent in tensorflow 2 the `ModelCheckpoint` creates a directory called `filepath` and when I follow the documentation [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/keras/save_and_load) to load the saved model I have to create an empty model then call `model.load_weights(filepath)`. 
Here is my callback and fit:

```
filepath = "filepath"
checkpoint = tf.keras.callbacks.ModelCheckpoint(filepath=filepath, mode='max', monitor='val_accuracy', verbose=2, save_best_only=True)
callbacks_list = [checkpoint]
model.fit(train_dataset, validation_data=y_test_dataset, validation_steps=BATCH_SIZE, callbacks=callbacks_list, epochs=5000, verbose=2, steps_per_epoch=(X_train_deleted_nans.shape[0]//BATCH_SIZE))
```

Doing `model.load_weights(filepath)` in another script I get the following error:

`OSError: Unable to open file (unable to open file: name = 'filepath', errno = 13, error message = 'Permission denied', flags = 0, o_flags = 0)`

I would like to get some help on why I would be getting a permission denied error for a model that I created.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try checkpointing while including the `.hdf5` extension when saving your model weights.

```py
filepath = "filepath/model.hdf5"
checkpoint = tf.keras.callbacks.ModelCheckpoint(filepath=filepath, mode='max', monitor='val_accuracy', verbose=2, save_best_only=True)
```

Comment: `tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.NotFoundError: Failed to create a directory: ./filepath.ckpt\variables; No such file or directory`

Comment: @Race save the model weights with a ```.hdf5``` extension firstly ```filepath = "filepath/model.hdf5"
checkpoint = tf.keras.callbacks.ModelCheckpoint(filepath=filepath, mode='max', monitor='val_accuracy', verbose=2, save_best_only=True)```
I realised the .hdf5 extension was missing when saving your weights .Let me update it in the answer

Answer (score 0):

What to do if you've spent much time training your model and you **don't want to do it again** just to save in HDF5 format?

What you can do:

1. Create your model from code `model = build_super_artificial_intelligence_deep_learning_model()`
2. Save it using `tf.keras.models.save_model(model, "/path/to/full_model")`
3. Replace the `variables.*` files in `/path/to/full_model/variables` with the files with the corresponding extensions in your checkpoint. Rename the files from the checkpoint to `variables.*`.
4. Load the model using `trained_model = tf.keras.models.load_model("/path/to/full_model")`.

(tested with TF2.5)